# How would you go about making this shape in CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have been scratching my head for days over trying to create this particular shape in CSS. I have tried messing with other shapes that are similar to this one, but I just can't get this exact shape. 
*Here is the shape I have been trying to create.*
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use images in your scenario?

Comment: SVG is what you should use if you are creating irregular shapes.

Comment: You can 'draw' with CSS if you're willing to create a lot of objects and use overlapping, borders, rotation, etc. There's not always a benefit to that, though, vs. just creating an image as an SVG or the like.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I'm kind of new to CSS, and I thought you would go about using it to create this shape. Now that I know more about SVG after looking it up, I think I can make that work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this using pseudo elements :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 340px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 10px solid green;
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 320px;
}

.container:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid green;
  width: 200%;
  height: 50px;
  top: -43px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 37%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}

.container:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid green;
  width: 200%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -43px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 37%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to control the curve with border-radius and the width of the pseudo-elements. You can play with these values and you will see the result (you may have to adjust top/left/bottom too)